# Invertible , bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose we have an invertible, bounded linear operator $K$ on a Hilbert space $H$. Is there a constant $c \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $$ ||Ku|| \geq c||u|| $$ for all $u \in H$ ?

Comment: Let $H=\mathbb R$, $K = x\mapsto x^3$. I'm guessing your actual question is about _linear_ invertible operators?

Comment: @AlexR I am sorry, I am considering linear bounded invertible operators, I just edited the question

Comment: If by "invertible" you mean "bijective" then this is a [well known theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Let $H=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ be the space of square-summable series, i.e. $$
  \big\langle (a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}},\;(b_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\big\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ib_i
$$ and therefore $$
  \|(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\|^2 = \big\langle(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}},\;(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\big\rangle =\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^2.
$$

Now look at the operator $$
  K \;:\; H\to H\;:\; (a)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \to (\tfrac{1}{n}a)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.
$$
and in particular at the images of the vectors $$
\mathbf{u}_i = (\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{i-1\text{ zeros}},1,0,\ldots).
$$

**Edit:** Note, however, that $K$ isn't *surjective*, only *injective*. So $K$ isn't *bijective*, although it *does* have a left-inverse (but no right-inverse).

Comment: I am sorry, I just edited the question. I am asking this question for bounded linear operators

Comment: @the8thone: $K$ *is* a bounded linear operator.

Comment: Nitpick: you don't really mean $H = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ which is the set of all sequences, not just those which are square-summable.  The usual notation for the space of square-summable sequences is $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: And the second display should have $\|(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\|^2$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yeah, I wanted to write $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ but couldn't figure out how to get the small script "l". Thanks to your comment I now know that the correct command is `\ell`. Will fix.

Comment: @NateEldredge On second thought, my operator is bounded, but since its also compact, it can't be invertible. It's definitely injective, but surjectivity fails I believe - there's no pre-image of $(\frac{1}{i^2})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, since the only candidate would be $(\frac{1}{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ but that doesn't lie in $H$. So I guess this is not what the OP was looking for (or I now managed to utterly confuse myself - it's late here...)

Comment: It depends on what exactly is meant by "invertible".  It has an inverse which is not defined on all of $H$.  If "invertible" means "bijective" then indeed your operator is not bijective, and in fact every bijective bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space does have a bounded inverse.